# How to efficiently "poke" a ByteString value of a given length at a Ptr?

Tags: haskell, ffi, bytestring

["Peeking"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:peek), to read a pointer `ptr` to  a new `ByteString`, is straightforward:

```
BS.packCStringLen (ptr, size)
```

But the [`poke`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#v:poke) operation (writing a `ByteString` into a given memory location) isn't that obvious. We have

```
useAsCStringLen :: ByteString -> (CStringLen -> IO a) -> IO a
```

so we could do (with the help of [`copyBytes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Utils.html).

```
BS.useAsCStringLen bs $ \(src, len) -> copyBytes ptr src len
```

or for better performance `unsafeUseAsCStringLen`.

Is there perhaps a ready-made function that does the above?

Comment: Wouldn't that break purity? Even if it's in IO, we can't usually change e.g. `x :: Int` to a different value...

Comment: @chi We're copying into `ptr`, leaving ByteString `src` intact, so if `ptr` is correctly handled, there won't be purity violations. But now I see the title might be a bit misleading, I'll update it.

Comment: Ah, now I see. You want to modify what the `ptr` points to, not the ByteString. I misread.